# How to change the Font in the entire Swing UI application

Tags: java, swing, fonts

I have made a swing application. Now I want to change the Font of entire Swing Application , so that any component being added should follow that Font only.
Is there any way to achieve the same ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
public static void setGlobalFont( Font font ) {  
        Enumeration keys = UIManager.getDefaults().keys();  
        while (keys.hasMoreElements() ) {  
            Object key = keys.nextElement();  
            Object value = UIManager.get( key );  
            if ( value instanceof Font ) {  
                UIManager.put( key, font );  
            }  
        }  
    }
```

Comment: Isn't it a little ... brute force ?

Comment: +1 well, yes, that's correct and in most cases works, but for some JComponents are needed force that with SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(myFrame/myDialog);

Comment: can't the above piece can't be changed so that [articular components can be provided with some font size differences, like I want JComboBox item having same UI default font size but JTable content with different fontSize

Comment: @Abhishek:  Now you are discovering the pitfalls of presuming that 'one `Font` fits all'.  ;)  To look at those `UIManager` values, and make better choices according to the use, see the [UIManager Defaults](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/09/uimanager-defaults/) of the current PLAF.