# How to change default font in netbeans platform?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, fonts, uimanager

I'd like to know how to change the default font used in netbeans platform. I'm not asking for changing the font in the **Netbeans IDE** but in the **platform**, then all my derived applications would use this default font.

A netbeans application is a group of *Jcomponent* so i could easily set the font of each of those components but there is still things like *notifications* that i can't access directly to change the font, so i think the best would be to change the font by default. Programmaticaly or any other way... maybe editing one the jar?

Comment: What do you mean by 'derived applications'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

type and size of `Font` are diferrent by `platform` and used `Look and Feel`, there are these possibilities

- [GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().registerFont(font);](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GraphicsEnvironment.html#getLocalGraphicsEnvironment%28%29)

and/or with

- change [Keys in UIManager](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6276613/714968) for current JVM instance

or

- [Change Font at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9958004/change-font-at-runtime)

have look at [UImanager default by @camickr](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/09/uimanager-defaults/)

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to change the **'editor' fonts in platform applications**, (i do use some of NB editors in my platform application), here is the way.

create a file `org-netbeans-modules-editor-settings-CustomFontsColors.xml` with the following contents,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE fontscolors PUBLIC "-//NetBeans//DTD Editor Fonts and Colors settings 1.1//EN" "http://www.netbeans.org/dtds/EditorFontsColors-1_1.dtd">
<fontscolors>
    <fontcolor bgColor="white" foreColor="black" name="default">
        <font name="Noto Serif CJK JP" size="15"/>
    </fontcolor>
</fontscolors>
```

and in your layer.xml file,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE filesystem PUBLIC "-//NetBeans//DTD Filesystem 1.2//EN" "http://www.netbeans.org/dtds/filesystem-1_2.dtd">
<filesystem>
     <folder name="Editors">
        <folder name="NetBeans">
            <folder name="Defaults">
                <file name="defaultColoring.xml" url="org-netbeans-modules-editor-settings-CustomFontsColors.xml"/>
            </folder>
        </folder>
     </folder>
</filesystem>
```

That's all.

PS: You can also check the source [here](https://github.com/apache/netbeans/blob/0f2e98d513deaedccef831ee9cfc08d09f3650b6/ide/editor.settings.storage/test/unit/src/org/netbeans/modules/editor/settings/storage/test-layer.xml)