# How to change Font in multiple Components at once which are already assigned with a Font?

Tags: java, swing, fonts, jframe, awt

How do I change an apply a different Font into multiple Components or the entire JFrame or the entire Swing Application, **which some Components are already assigned with a Font, after the UI is generated**?

The task I'm trying to do is to change and apply a different or custom Font into JFrame upon loading which is in a NetBeans Project therefore some of the Components are already assigned with a Font by its auto generated methods.

So far I have tried setting the Font using the `UIManager` into its default keys, and then calling `SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(jframe);` but it only applied the Font to the Components those have not been assigned with a Font already. Here is how I made the attempt (with the example of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6276613/3127619).).

```
        Enumeration enc = UIManager.getDefaults().keys();

        while (en.hasMoreElements() ) {
            Object key = en.nextElement();
            Object value = UIManager.get(key);
            if (value instanceof Font) {
                UIManager.put(key, font);
            }
        }
```

And then calling,

```
SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(jframe);
```

As it was not entirely successful, then I tried to set the Font in all the Components in the JFrame and then calling `validate();` followed by `repaint();`, but it didn't make any effect whatsoever. This is how I tried to do it.

```
        Component[] comps = this.getComponents();
        for (Component comp : comps){
            comp.setFont(font);
        }
```

And then calling,

```
this.validate();
this.repaint();
```

Have I done those previous steps correctly or is there any error I have made? If not, what is the correct way to accomplish my task? And also, even though I need to change the Font in all the Components, their existing Font sizes and Font styles are needed to be preserved as well.

Thank you!

Comment: Could you show the code of "As it was not entirely successful, then I tried to set the Font in all the Components in the JFrame"? For me it should work

Comment: no issue, for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) / [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), short runnable, compilable

Comment: Thanks to both of you for the suggestion and guidance. I have updated the question with the codes I used in my attempts. I hope I did it right.

Comment: updateComponentTree should work - if it doesn't there's something wrong with the code you are not showing (please read the articles @mKorbel reference, your snippets are _not_ what's needed to help you)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the Pluggable Look and Feel to a (possibly custom) PLAF is the best, most robust way to do it.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) for tips on how to change the PLAF after the GUI is visible.

See the [Modifying the Look and Feel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/) lesson of the Java Tutorial for further details.  See below for examples of one user interface using two different PLAFs.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your guidance. So far it looks like the only way I have to do this is by using the `SynthLookAndFeel` and defining the Font, since what I need is to change the entire application's default font into a custom font of my preference, or else I still have to learn more about this. I will update my progress as it happens. Thanks again. I would definitely +1 this but I lack the 15 reputation to do so.

Comment: Haha. Indeed. With your help I no longer lack it. Thank you! :)

Comment: Sorry for taking a long time to accept it. It was so hard for me to try out on these with the limited time I've got. However. I must say the path you showed me was absolutely right and I accomplished the task by modifying the LAF, yet I still have a lot to learn and the guidance you gave me will lead me through it. Thanks again! :)